# Inverse of matrix which depends on element indicies

Tags: matrices

Lets say that I have a square matrix of arbitrary size where each element is defined as $x_{i,j} = b*a^{(i+j)} + c*a^{(i-j)}$, where a, b, c are constants and a is between 0 and 1. Is there any analytical formula to find the inverse of this matrix. I feel like this type of matrix should have been analyzed already in some textbook; but, I can't find it. It would be helpful if at least someone knows what this type of matrix is called.

Comment: That matrix is the sum of a Toeplitz matrix and a Hankel matrix. I don't know if those kinds of matrices have a special name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the matrix $X$ you gave is of size $n \times n$ where $n \ge 2$, then $X$ is not invertible.

Specifically, the matrix given by $X_{i,j} = ba^{i+j}+ca^{i-j}$ has rank $1$.

To see this, note that $X_{i,j} = a^i(ba^j+ca^{-j})$. Hence, $$X = \begin{bmatrix}a \\ a^2 \\ \vdots \\ a^n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}ba+ca^{-1} & ba^2+ca^{-2} & \cdots & ba^n+ca^{-n} \end{bmatrix}.$$

Since $X$ is the product of a non-zero $n \times 1$ matrix and a non-zero  $1 \times n$ matrix, $X$ has rank $1$.

So, if $n \ge 2$, then $X$ is rank deficient, and thus, $X$ is not invertible.

Comment: Yeah, you are right about that. Wow, didn't think before asking.